# Chef server generating bad public keys?

Tags: openssl, chef-infra

Here's what I did:

- Created a new client in the Chef web UI.
- Kept the window open showing the public and private key it generated.
- Saved off the private key into `client.pem` on the Chef server itself.
- Re-generated the public key on the Chef server using this command:

  ```
  openssl rsa -in client.pem -pubout
  ```
- The output doesn't match the public key from the web UI. The result is the same on my workstation, thus `knife` can't authenticate. I tried this a few times thinking I was going insane.

What am I doing wrong?

Chef 10.18.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by upgrading to Chef 11.